# Symfony login don't authenticate users

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm new here and I'm from abroad, so sorry for my mistakes in English. Okey, so I have problem with login system in my first application in Symfony. Before I was writing some simple apps in Laravel. But here, I don't know what's wrong. I made new bundle and my login system stop working. I can put data in form, but when I pass it to authorization, website redirects me to login page and I'm not logged in. This is my code:

Controller:

```
 <?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="user_registration")
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        // 1) build the form
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

        // 2) handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            // 4) save the User!
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            // ... do any other work - like sending them an email, etc
            // maybe set a "flash" success message for the user

            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'registration/registration.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="user_login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request) {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();        
        return $this->render('registration/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="user_login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction() {
        throw new \Exception('This should never be reached!');      
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="user_logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        throw new \Exception('This should never be reached!');
    }   


    /**
     * @Route("/login_failed", name="user_login_fail")
     */
    public function loginError() {
        return new Response('ERROR');
    }
}
```

security.yml

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        # Our user class and the algorithm we'll use to encode passwords
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
         our_db_provider:
             entity:
                 class: AppBundle:User
                 property: username
    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: user_login
                check_path: user_login_check
                failure_path: user_login_fail
            logout:
                path: user_logout
                target: homepage                
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}   
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

User Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * User
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setIsActive(TRUE);
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }   

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt algorithm doesn't require a separate salt.
        // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
        return null;
    }   

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }   
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `http_basic: ~` is for authentication with the HTTP "alert". While use it alongside with form login?

Comment: and why 2 firewalls? thanks